# MySql SUM ALIAS

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, alias

I have a problem with mysql alias.

I have this query:

```
SELECT (`number_of_rooms`) AS total, id_room_type, 
     COUNT( fk_room_type ) AS reservation , 
     SUM(number_of_rooms - reservation) AS result
FROM room_type
    LEFT JOIN room_type_reservation 
         ON id_room_type = fk_room_type
WHERE  result > 10
GROUP BY id_room_type
```

My problem start from `SUM`, `cannot recognize reservation` and then i want to use the result for a where condition.  Like (`where result > 10`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% but to the best of my knowledge you cant use aliases in your declarations, and thats why you are getting the column issue. Try this:

```
 SELECT (`number_of_rooms`) AS total, id_room_type,
     COUNT( fk_room_type ) AS reservation , 
     SUM(number_of_rooms - COUNT( fk_room_type ) ) AS result
 FROM room_type
     LEFT JOIN room_type_reservation 
         ON id_room_type = fk_room_type
 GROUP BY id_room_type
 Having SUM(number_of_rooms - COUNT( fk_room_type ) ) > 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have ready do this and returns me #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: Lets see, one more try, it might be a bracketing issue.

 `SELECT ('number_of_rooms') AS total, id_room_type,
     COUNT( fk_room_type ) AS reservation , 
     SUM(number_of_rooms) - COUNT( fk_room_type )  AS result
 FROM room_type
     LEFT JOIN room_type_reservation 
         ON id_room_type = fk_room_type
 GROUP BY id_room_type
 Having SUM(number_of_rooms) - COUNT( fk_room_type )  > 10`

Comment: Thanks again but the results its not correct
total
id_room_type
reservation
result
20
10
201
3819
200
11
10
1990
10
22
100
900
22
25
0
22

Comment: Thanks for your time but i find the solution with nested select
SELECT (
 `number_of_rooms`
) AS total, id_room_type, c.reservation, SUM( number_of_rooms - c.reservation ) AS result
FROM room_type
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT number_of_rooms AS moutsela, fk_room_type, COUNT( fk_room_type ) AS reservation
FROM room_type
LEFT JOIN room_type_reservation ON id_room_type = fk_room_type
GROUP BY id_room_type
)c ON id_room_type = fk_room_type
GROUP BY id_room_type
LIMIT 0 , 30

but i ll try to find the way to optimize my query

Comment: that is why i wanted to se your table structures :)

Comment: Table : room_type_reservation    
  1 id_room_type_reservation int(11)     
  2 fk_room_type int(11)   
  3 start datetime   
  4 end datetime 
  
  Table : room_type
  1 id_room_type int(11)
  2  number_of_rooms int(11)

Comment: Lets see if this is what your looking for:

`SELECT
id_room_type,
(SELECT COUNT(fk_room_type) FROM room_type_reservation WHERE fk_room_type = id_room_type) AS 'reservation',
SUM(number_of_rooms)-(SELECT COUNT(fk_room_type) FROM room_type_reservation WHERE fk_room_type = id_room_type) AS 'result'
FROM room_type
GROUP BY id_room_type`

Comment: Your solution its better from my query (in explain) . Thank you very much for your time !!!!

Answer (score 1):

To apply a predicate (filter condition) on the result of an aggregate function, you use a Having clause.  Where clause expressions are only applicable to intermediate result sets created prior to any aggregation.

```
 SELECT (`number_of_rooms`) AS total, id_room_type,
     COUNT( fk_room_type ) AS reservation , 
     SUM(number_of_rooms - reservation) AS result
 FROM room_type
     LEFT JOIN room_type_reservation 
         ON id_room_type = fk_room_type
 GROUP BY id_room_type
 Having SUM(number_of_rooms - reservation) > 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but SUM(number_of_rooms - reservation) AS result returns me #1054 - Unknown column 'reservation' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap it into one more SELECT

```
SELECT t.*, t.number_of_rooms - t.reservation AS result FROM
  (
    SELECT (`number_of_rooms`) AS total, id_room_type, 
     COUNT( fk_room_type ) AS reservation , 
     SUM(number_of_rooms - reservation) AS result
     FROM room_type
     LEFT JOIN room_type_reservation 
         ON id_room_type = fk_room_type
     WHERE  result > 10
     GROUP BY id_room_type
   ) t
```

Comment: I solved this in MySQL with a function here is the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372961/mysql-use-aliased-fields-in-aggregate-functions/76495570#76495570