# How to calculate sum from Alias column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have two columns: total and percentage. I have made a new total column by using Alias and now I want to get a percentage column by finding the sum of this and the Alias total column. What I have tried is as follows:

```
SELECT sum(CASE when quality_class =1  then
    trees_ha else 0 end)/get_total_forest_plots()  +
sum(CASE when quality_class =2  then
    trees_ha else 0 end)/get_total_forest_plots()  as total ,

(sum(CASE when quality_class =1  then
     trees_ha else 0 end)/get_total_forest_plots()  +   
sum(CASE when quality_class =3  then
    trees_ha else 0 end)/get_total_forest_plots())/sum(total) *100 as percentage from (SELECT nested query from my_table);
```

I used this sum (total) method, but I get the error as ERROR:  column "total" does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't use the alias at the same level. You need to write an upper layer of query to use the alias
Considering the logic of the code is already working, just correcting the syntax to use alias
Here is how it is

```
SELECT 
   sum(CASE when quality_class =1 then trees_ha else 0 end)/get_total_forest_plots() + sum(CASE when quality_class =3 then trees_ha else 0 end)/get_total_forest_plots())/sum(initial_data.total) *1
FROM
    (SELECT 
    sum(CASE when quality_class =1 then trees_ha else 0 end)/get_total_forest_plots() + sum(CASE when quality_class =2 then trees_ha else 0 end)/get_total_forest_plots() as total 
From
<Table name> 
) initial_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

```
SELECT 3 x, (SELECT 1+1) y, 3-(SELECT 1+1) z;
```

Or

Option 2

```
SELECT x, y, x-y z FROM
  ( SELECT 3 x, (SELECT 1+1) y) q
```

Comment: This isn't an exact answer but you will be able to adapt this solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372961/mysql-use-aliased-fields-in-aggregate-functions/76495570#76495570